# Taxonomy Term Field of a Reference Field in a Product not available in Data Selector for CheckOut Rules

Tags: 7, commerce, taxonomy-terms, rules, actions

I installed Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2 with drupal version 7.54 and drupal commerce Version: 7.x-1.14. My problem is I want to send email to the store owner every time an order is completed. So in `CheckOut Rules`, I created a rule `Commerce order message: order notification e-mail`.

My Event is `Completing the CheckOut Process.`
My Action is to `Send Mail` but in the `To` field, I could not find the right replacement pattern I need. The referenced custom field `field_store_email_address` was not available there. Below is the setup

My website sells Pizza, so I have a `Pizza` content type. In the Pizza content type my fields are `Store(field_store)` and I will not name other unrelated fields. The `field_store` in my Pizza content type is a term reference to a vocabulary taxonomy `Store`.  In the taxonomy `Store`, it has a field `store_email_address(field_store_email_address)`. `field_store_email_address` is where I want to send my email.

When the checkout process is completed, I want to send an email to unique store owners of items included in the order. So my question here is how will I formulate my `Conditions Rules`? Please help me.

Comment: Drupal and Commerce versions?

Comment: @IsmailCherri--> I installed Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2 with drupal version 7.54 and drupal commerce Version: 7.x-1.14

Answer (score 2):

D7, install [Conditional rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional), this module let's you add aditional conditions at action section in rules UI.

You say your event  is 'checkout proccess', so, the first thing you need is to load your 'pizza' node object in to rules, I am assuming that you have a field in your product-fields referencing to your 'pizza-content-type'.

To do this, in actions UI add a conditional, add and if, entity has field, your product-field that is referencing to pizza-content-type, if true (always be true, but you need this so rules can load your pizza-node), then fetch entity-by-id, your pizza-node, now you have pizza-object available

Add another conditional, add another if, entity has field, your taxonomy-term related to taxonomy store, then, fetch entity by id, your taxonomy term, now you have available taxonomy term related to store, then add a conditional, entity has field, your taxonomy-term `field_store_email_address`, and now you have now available  `field_store_email_address` value in rules, send your email, done.

Here is an img that look alike what your rules action will look.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but every time I install Conditional rules Module using drush, my site crashes. Good thing I have my database backup.

Comment: I installed it using the command drush en rules_conditional

Comment: install rules Development version: 7.x-2.x-dev, or Version: 7.x-2.11, then conditional rules, to avoid updating rules version install https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_updates

Comment: is there anything else you need from me to accomplish your task?