# Fields missing on "Create a new entity" for Entityform submission

Tags: 7, rules

I'm using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to create node from [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) submission. When I add an action with "Create a new entity", there is only one field ("title" value) available. How can I get the other fields from node type(content type)?

PS: Same issue with webform + webform rules.

**- - update: add screenshots with Conditional Rules Setting - -**

As you can see the "Create a new entity" only have Title and Author" fields available event I have other field tokens available.
[image]

[image]

Comment: D7, you could try conditional rules module, and make some conditional with several IF's like: entity has field', if so, you will have avalible in rules whatever you like.

Comment: @pinueve I did if "Entity has field" data-selector = "entityform", field value = "body", still nothing come up.

Comment: https://imgur.com/vZGMhJq

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/280688/taxonomy-term-field-of-a-reference-field-in-a-product-not-available-in-data-sele/280796#280796

Comment: See updated screenshots. I added if statements and nothing changes on "Create a new entity". Am I missing something?

Comment: i do not know if is a bug in rules combined with conditional rules, downgrade rules module to Version: 7.x-2.11, so you can 'see' your images same as mine

Comment: Same issue after downgrade. I done this with "Create a new entity" for "user" without any issue. What version of Conditional Rules you are using?

Comment: Version: 7.x-1.0-beta2

Comment: :( I even tried in a fresh Drupal 7 installation without any different. Have you tried with "Create a new entity > Node"?

Comment: i have done magic combining these two modules, i do not understand where you are having problems, it's a kind of logic how are conneted your entitys by an entity-reference fields, grab this first, then you fecth entity by id with ER-field value, after that now you have new objects avialible in rules.   https://imgur.com/RemSzjP

Comment: @pinueve Finally the issue is solved. The new value will never display in "Create a new entity". What I did is, I add the "If: Entity has field", "Create a new entity", and "Set a data value". Adding "Set a data value" after "Create a new entity" is the key.